# Qt Ui Existing But Ui Header and Source Not Existing

Tags: c++, qt

I have received a demo Qt project for a product.
I am trying to build the project and run it.
I am getting such a kind of error in Qt Designer when I try to build the project.
It says ui_FOO.h does not exist.
I see that FOO.ui (the qt designer form exists) but source and header files for it do not exist. And thats why i am getting the error. 
What should I do to be able to build and run my project?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the pro file to get [uic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) generate the C++ header from the ui file:

```
FORMS = FOO.ui
```

and build your project again.

You can find more information from [Using a Designer UI File in Your Application](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it.
This is a qt4 project as it is written in manual.
I went under tools->options->build&run->qtversions and added qmake-qt4
Then under the kit manually added a kit which uses the qtversion that i just specified.
Then under projects tile clicked on add kit and the kit appeared.
I removed the qt5 kit.

Now those ui_foo.h file is generated in its corresponding build path.